# Array of objects in Swagger docs and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using https://github.com/rswag/rswag gem to wrap Swagger.

I have query parameter called `filter` which accepts array of objects and in proper way generated looks like this:

```
filters[][attribute_name]=test&filters[][operator]=test&filters[][value]=test&filters[][attribute_name]=test&filters[][operator]=test&filters[][value]=test
```

When I'm trying to generate the same parameters through Swagger, with parameter defined this way:

```
parameter name: 'filters[]', in: :query, description: 'filters',
              schema: { type: :array, items: { '$ref': '#/components/schemas/filter' } }
    filter: {
            type: 'object',
            properties: {
              attribute_name: {
                type: 'string',
                description: 'name of the object'
              },
              operator: {
                type: 'string',
                description: 'name of the object'
              },
              value: {
                type: 'string',
                description: 'name of the object'
              }
            }
          }
```

The parameter which is being created looks like this:

```
filters[]={
  "attribute_name": "test",
  "operator": "test",
  "value": "test"
},{
  "attribute_name": "test",
  "operator": "test",
  "value": "test"
}
```

Can I somehow achieve proper parameters